# How to return the original value in a .apply function

Tags: python, pandas

I Am trying to use the .apply() method in Pandas.

I want to changed certain rows and return with a new value but return the original value for others.

Here is what I have:

```
def pre(row):
    if row['HOURLYWindDirection'] == 'VRB':
        return 'Variable Direction'
    else row['HOURLYWindDirection'] == float : # I don't know what to write here
        return  #or here
dfWeather['HOURLYWindDirection'] = dfWeather.apply(pre,axis='columns')
```

This returns:

```
0                      None
1                      None
2        Variable Direction
3                      None
4                      None
```

But I want it to return the original values not 'None'

I've tried pass and continue in the 'Pre' function.

Any advice?

Have to use the .apply function

Comment: I was trying to say if it is a float (not a string) to skip

Comment: So it would be 

elif:
    pass or continue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function does not do what you intend to do. When you use `apply` function, it is always used on a pandas series objects. In the case of data frames, every column is one series object. So what you should do is to use the apply function on a column you need and you dont have to write a function. What you can do is this:

```py
dfWeather['HOURLYWindDirection'] = dfWeather.apply(lambda x: 'Variable Direction' if x == 'VRB' else x)
```

The above code returns 'Variable Direction' if the row value is 'VRB' for that column. If you don't know about `lambda` functions here is another version similar to yours:

```py
def pre(x):
    if x == 'VRB':
        return 'Variable Direction'
    else:
        return x
```

Let me know, if that helps

Comment: def pre(x):
    if x['HOURLYWindDirection'] == 'VRB':
        return 'Variable Direction'
    else:
        return x['HOURLYWindDirection']